# Autocomplete input for filter more options within FormGroup

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I need to implement a simple autocomplete textbox that allow to choose from list of objects filtered and displayed by name.

For example i have a array of Country objects that have some property (countryName, countryCode, countryId.. so on), i want to display and filter in the textbox by countryName but once user select the country i want that whole object gets selected.

I could solve this problem with `[(ngModel)]` or `FormControl` but now i have to use `FormGroup` and i can't figure out how to use property `formControlName="..."`

here's snippet example:

**.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
 [...]
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{'BIRTH_COUNTRY'|translate}}" matInput formControlName="birthCountry"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto" required>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">
        {{country.CountryName}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**.ts**

```
export class PersonalDataComponent implements OnInit {
  public formGroup: FormGroup;

  countries?: Country[];

  constructor(public service: RegisterService) {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      lastName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      gender: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      birthDate: new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, legalAgeValidator])),
      birthCountry: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
    });

    displayFn(country ?: Country): string | undefined {
      return country ? country.CountryName : undefined;
    }

  }
}
```

is there any solution to use a autocomplete textbox/select to filter object list and bind the selected element to a `FormGroup` element?

Comment: i think you should remove  [displayWith]="displayFn"  and refer this [link](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#adding-a-custom-filter)

Comment: i already tried to follow the angular's documentation but it only solves problems with [formControl] and not with entire formgroups... i mean there's a example with formControName="...", but can't apply it to my problem... i have to manage entire objects and not only a single string like in the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

Ok I got it to work with autoComplete. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
        <mat-form-field>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Country" aria-label="Country" matInput formControlName="country"
            [matAutocomplete]="auto">
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let country of filteredCountries | async" [value]="country">
              {{country.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
```

TS:
Before @Component

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
export interface Country {
  name: string;
  id: string;
}
```

Before constructor:

```
 public formGroup;
 countries: Country[] = [{"name": 'Greece', "id": "1"}, {"name": 'Italy', "id": "2"}, {"name": 'Spain', "id": "3"}]
 filteredCountries: Observable<Country[]>;
```

Constructor:

```
constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder)
```

After constructor:

```
this.formGroup =  this.formBuilder.group({
country: ['', Validators.required]});
```

On ngOnInit:

```
 this.filteredCountries = this.formGroup.get('country').valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith<string | Country>(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : (<any>value).name),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.countries.slice())
      );
```

Additional functions:

```
 displayFn(country?: Country): string | undefined {
    return country ? country.name : undefined;
  }

  private _filter(name): Country[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.countries.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
```

I used the material documentation to get it to work, and added it to an existing project of mine. If you find any region reference instead of country its because that was the keyword in my project and I apologize in advance. This will make the value take the whole object. You can test and print  `console.log(this.formGroup.value);`
onSubmit.

Comment: i've already tried this solution, unfortunately nothing changed.. but anyway this is the right way to define formgroups in a simplified way

Comment: You can try mat-select instead of auto-complete. It definetely works with objects I have used it before. You can then use an input to filter the select options with javascript with *ngFor="let country of filteredCountries  | async" like the autoComplete documentation(https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview). I will try it myself and come back to you soon.

Comment: ok perfect, let me know if you need further informations. I tried mat-select too, but it seems it doesn't support the kind of autocomplete that i need... it just moves the focus on the element of the list while typing, but i need a strong filtering on that list

Comment: Check out my edit and tell me if you have anything else need sorting out

Comment: It seems to work just perfectly, at least i have a point where to start! thank you very much!